# Android MVP - screen orientation - retain presenters state

Tags: android, retrofit, mvp, mosby

I have a question regarding MVP pattern in Android. I want to write my own "application core" which will have base classes for presenters, views etc. It has to be simple, clean and "stable". My idea is very similiar to what Mosby has to offer, I'm trying to achive something like this:

1. Each **Activity** has it's own **Presenter**, **View** (interface
   to communicate with Activity), **ViewState** (parcelable object that
   holds persistent data).
2. When **Activity** is being *destroyed*:

   - detach View
   - save ViewState in bundle
   - cancel all background tasks in Presenter (tasks that updates View when finished)
   - destroy Presenter
3. When **Activity** is being *recreated*:

   - attach View
   - restore ViewState
   - create new instance of Presenter
   - restart background tasks that have been canceled

I've got almost eveything done except that last issue - *"restart background tasks that has been canceled"*. It will be easier to discuss it with an example. So let's say I have two methods in a presenter (Retrofit 2 calls):

- **downloadUsers()** - fetches users data from web server and onSuccess updates view
- **downloadProject()** - fetches project info from web server and onSuccess updates view

Now user is changing configuration when one of those calls has been started but not finished yet. **How will I know which one of them I should restart when Presenter will be recreated?**

The only idea that comes to my mind is create a persitent boolean flag for each task, set it *true* when task is starting, and *false* when it is finished. When Presenter will be created I will check every flag and restart corresponding calls.

**What do you think about it? How it can be improved? Any other ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your UI looks like, but to me it sounds that you should split your one big View into two subviews:

- `DownloadUsersView` + ViewState  managed by a `DownloadUsersPresenter`
- `DownloadProjectsView` + ViewState managed by a `DownloadProjectsPresenter`

From my point of view it is always a good idea that MVP has exactly one single Model that gets displayed in the View (and not two like in your scenario). Usually if you have to deal with two models in the same view it is a indicator that you can split this view and presenter into two distinct.

Alternatively, you can merge your two models into one single Model, saying

```
class DownloadModel {
  List<User> users;
  List<Project> projects;
}
```

and then you combine your two Retrofit calls to create a `DownloadModel` and when both calls are completed you can display the `DownloadModel` inside your view. With retrofit and rxjava this is quite simple (see `combineLatest()` operator). In that case you don't have that problem because your `Presenter` only has one `download()` methods which downloads both in parallel. If one is significant faster then the other, then it's very likely that after orientation changes and recreation of the presenter the faster one comes from retrofit cache so this shouldn't bother you to much.

As you have already said you could also start keeping track in the presenter which http call was executing before and reinvoke them once the presenter gets re-instantiated, but that means that the presenter has to save it's internal state as well into the bundle. Mosby don't make any specification about that and assumes that in general there is no such need. Hence Mosby's default Presenter implementation doesn't provide a `presenter.saveInstanceState(Bundle)` and `presenter.restoreInstanceState(Bundle)`. But that doesn't mean that you can not / should not do that. You can do that in Mosby and in your implementation as well. However, if you start doing so then you just move the spaghetti code previously (without mvp) sitting in the Activity class into the presenter.

Therefore, once again, I strongly recommend to have one single model per view in MVP.

Btw. why reinventing the wheel? Sounds like Mosby is already providing the things you are looking for. Mosby also supports retaining presenter which are surviving screen orientation changes.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer. I'm doing this mostly for educational purposes - I want to play around with generics, understand android lifecycle and learn how not to create memory leakages :)


I wanted include presenter's state into VIewState and save all and restore in one bundle. But now I see it's a bad idea. Good point with spaghetti.


I agree that Presenter should handle only one model. I picked out unfortunate names in above example. Let's change it to:

downloadUsers() - Retrofit call; 
storeUsers() - save downloaded data in database. 

Should I also find a solution using Rx?

Comment: @rafakob your problem is that you see MVP as solution for everything regarding scheduling of async background tasks. MVP main purpose is to decouple View from Model and having one Presenter as "coordinator" sitting in between. In your example: It might be a good idea that `storeUsers()` is executed in it's own android service, because you don't want to re-execute `storeUser()` on screen orientation changes, right? So execute `storeUser()` in a service, make the presenter observe the service (eventbus, rxjava or whatever you are comfortable with).

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches and solutions. The one I like is to use Loaders api. Here is simple library you can make use for purpose of persisting presenter instances accross orientation changes https://github.com/samiuelson/Preservely.